# Trying to assign a spatial reference to a polygon in R

Tags: r, coordinates, polygon, raster, spatial

I am trying to generate randomly shaped and sized plots that will cover 85% of a raster image. This is what I have so far, but I keep getting an error message. I've tried a bunch of different iterations of this and still the message persists. If anyone can find the error, I would greatly appreciate it.

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘proj4string<-’ for signature ‘"Polygon", "CRS"’

```
library(sp)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgeos)
library(sf)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

# image
site <- raster("C:/Users/ichth/OneDrive/Documents/Restoration_Implementation/Design_Project/Site_Raster.tif")

# plot size min/max in pixels
plot_size <- c(10, 25)

# find raster total area
total_area <- cellStats(site, sum)

# find area needed to cover 85%
target_area <- 0.85 * total_area

# create empty data frame 
plots <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(
  SpatialPolygons(list()), 
  data.frame(id = numeric(), area = numeric(), row.names = character()),
  match.ID = FALSE
)

# loop until target reached
while (sum(plots$area) < target_area) {
  
  # next plot random location and size
  x <- runif(1, xmin(site), xmax(site))
  y <- runif(1, ymin(site), ymax(site))
  size <- runif(1, plot_size[1], plot_size[2])
  
  # set coordinate system for plots
  crs(site) <- "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=24.3333333333333 +lon_0=-81 +k=0.999941177 +x_0=200000.0001016 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs"
  
  # create overall polygon
  pol <- Polygon(
    matrix(
      c(x, x + size, x + size, x, x, 
        y, y, y + size, y + size, y),
      ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
  
  # set coordinate system for plots
  proj4string(pol) <- CRS(as.character(crs(site)))
  
  # add to plots data frame
  spatial_poly <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(pol), ID = as.character(length(plots) + 1))))
  plots <- rbind(plots, data.frame(id = length(plots) + 1, area = gArea(pol), row.names = as.character(length(plots) + 1)))
  coordinates(plots) <- c("x", "y")
  
  
  # check if target area has been reached
  if (sum(plots$area) >= target_area) {
    break
  }
  
  # plot on raster
  ggplot() +
    geom_raster(data = as.data.frame(site), aes(x = x, y = y, fill = value)) +
    geom_polygon(data = as.data.frame(plots), aes(x = x, y = y, fill = area), color = "white", alpha = 0.7) +
    coord_equal() +
    theme_void() +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red")
}

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘proj4string<-’ for signature ‘"Polygon", "CRS"’
```

Comment: Can you please edit your code to make it *minimal* (only include code needed to generate the error; so remove, e.g. calls to ggplot; and you can probably remove the loop as well) and *reproducible*  (replace the raster with one that ships with R or one that you generate in memory).

Answer (score 0):

`Polygon` objects are purely geometric and have no coordinate references. Hence a minimal illustration of what I think is causing your error message is:

```
> pol = Polygon(coords=cbind(c(0,1,1,0,0), c(0,0,1,1,0)))
> proj4string(pol)=CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘proj4string<-’ for signature ‘"Polygon", "CRS"’
>
```

`SpatialPolygons` do have coordinate systems, which you have written code to construct so I assume you know how to do this for your data. Here's how I do it with my example:

```
> spol = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(pol),ID=1)))
> proj4string(spol)=CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
```

You can do this in one line with an extra argument to `SpatialPolygons`:

```
> spol = SpatialPolygons(
       list(Polygons(list(pol),ID=1)),
       proj4string=CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
       )
>
```